# Cracking and pop when ipad plugged in to piano line in

Tags: ipad, cracking, snap-crackle-pop

I been trying to plug my ipad into line-in of my digital piano, and it works fine. Until I try to charge the ipad, as soon as I plug in the ipad I get a lot of hissing and cracking and pop. What could cause this?

Comment: Is there a working ground pin on the charger?

Comment: Phone chargers don't have an electrical ground, even if they have the 3rd pin. They're double-insulated devices & prone to floating voltages.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, I read that ipads are nutorious for high floativg voltages. But on [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2463442?start=60&tstart=0), [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2463442?start=45&tstart=0) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4778279?start=0&tstart=0)  grounding the devices was mentioned. Anyway I think this sentence summs it up _"Apple have put size and form over function and omited a lot of the electrics that normal transformers have..."_

Comment: [This is interesting](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3527397?tstart=0); a sound engineer doing tests with crackling and popping on his ipad.